# Ruby can't read TCP socket when run in background

Tags: ruby, linux, debian

I was writing a Slack bot in Ruby under Windows and everything worked just fine until I decided to run it on a Linux server. When I access my shell and run the script it works correctly in the foreground, but once I move it to the background it stops working. I'm getting a timeout error on a HTTP request with Net::HTTP, or an EOFError on the socket read.

I'm using Ruby 2.3 on Debian 7.

I think that the Ruby process stops on its own, because I only get the errors once I return the process to the foreground, and, if I run `ps aux` when the process is in the background it has the "T" (stopped) flag listed.

Since I want to become more familiar with Linux, I'd like to know what is causing the issue, rather than how to solve it.

EDIT: I found that my user input handler is causing the problem. Here is the problematic bit:

```
def input_handler
  return Thread.new {
    loop do
      user_input = gets.chomp
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: It's not a Ruby problem since there are many Ruby-based HTTP clients and HTTPd that run fine in the background. The problem is with your script or your configuration. But we can't help you unless you tell us more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: If you want to understand why it's happening then [su] might be a better site to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like it's `gets`.

By default `gets` reads from STDIN. [The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) says:

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

The code/thread will stop and wait for a prompt from the keyboard, or read from the piped input if STDIN is redirected or from a file given as a parameter to the script on the command-line.

Comment: I don't really understand this behavior. Shouldn't only the thread stop and wait for keyboard input, instead of the whole script?